# a bash command that uses the output of another bash command

Tags: linux, bash

I have a group of machines at google cloud. 
from my localhost:

```
gcloud compute instance-groups list-instances workers
OUTPUT:
NAME              ZONE           STATUS
workers-lya2    us-central1-a     RUNNING 
workers-23d4     us-central1-a     RUNNING 
...
workers-3asd3     us-central1-a     RUNNING
```

I want a random worker name from that list (let's say `workers-23d4`) and it's zone `us-central1-m` from the first command and paste it into this command:

```
gcloud compute --project "my-project" ssh --zone "<zone_name_from_first_command> "<machine_name_from_first_command>"
```

little weak on bash. please help

Comment: which one do you need? A random one? Or a specific one which matches a string?

Comment: sorry for not being clear. will edit the question. i meant a random one

Comment: thanks, now it's clear. I added my attempt at the problem as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gcloud compute instance-groups list-instances workers | grep -v "^NAME"  | shuf -n 1 | awk '{print $1, $2}' | 
while read machine zone; do
    export SELECTED_MACHINE="$machine"
    export SELECTED_ZONE="$zone"
done
gcloud compute --project "my-project" ssh --zone "$SELECTED_ZONE" "$SELECTED_MACHINE"
```

- `grep -v "^NAME"` strips away all lines starting with `NAME` (assuming it's just the first line you want to strip away)
- `shuf` takes a random line from the remaining lines
- `awk '{print $1, $2}'` splits the line at the spaces and prints the first and second column
- `while read` reads the output of awk into variables `$machine` and `$zone`

**Update**: The above code works for zsh, but not for bash, as bash runs the pipes in subshells (zsh doesn't) and [`export` does only pass variables to subprocesses](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-export), not to parent processes. The following script solves this problem through having `read` running in the parent process:

```
machine_zone=$(gcloud compute instance-groups list-instances workers | 
              grep -v "^NAME"  | shuf -n 1 | awk '{print $1, $2}')
read machine zone <<< $machine_zone
gcloud compute --project "my-project" ssh --zone "$zone" "$machine"
```

Comment: @hansplast thanks for that.`Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`

Comment: Solved that by exporting the variables into `export SELECTED_MACHINE="$machine"` like so. and then using them outside the `while`. change your answer and i'll accept. thanks

Comment: @WebQube ok, solved it like that for the moment, although it doesn't feel right, I'll look into that later

Comment: ++ for the part that extracts the random line, but since your `read` command executes in a _subshell_ (due to use of a pipelin), the 2nd `gcloud` command won't see the variables you're defining - whether you export them or not; also, you don't need a _loop_ to read the single-line output from `awk`.

Comment: @mklement0 thanks for the explanation. So in fact every piped command is a subshell (as documented in [man bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)) which has `stdin` wired to the `stdout` of the preceding command and therefore stdin is no peudo terminal. I guess there is no way around that when using pipes, right?

Comment: In Bash v4.2+ you can use `shopt -ls lastpipe` to make the _last_ pipeline segment run in the current shell, but there are simpler alternatives: use a process substitution or a command substitution with a here-string. The error message `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal` is unrelated to this; it is an `ssh` error message, and why it would happen here I don't know. (It normally surfaces if you use `ssh -t` while redirecting stdin input).

Comment: @mklement0 I have added new script which addresses the issue with export not handing over env variables to parent process through having `read` in the parent process

Comment: Thanks for updating. `zsh` doesn't pass child-process environment variables to the current process either (no shell does that), but it doesn't run the `read` command in a _subhell_ - that's why it works - no need for environment variables in either case. You still don't need a _loop_ to read the values. As an aside: better to use [command-substitution syntax `$(...)` instead of legacy syntax \`...\`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Comment: @mklement0 aha, that makes sense. I updated my explanation and also replaced the backticks against `$(...)`, thanks for the link. I never understood why `$(..)` is preferred over backticks, now I do

Answer (score 3):

The following command picks a random line (excluding the header) from the output of the *gcloud* command, then stores the first two "words" into `machine` and `zone` variables:

```
read -r machine zone unused <<< $(
  gcloud compute instance-groups list-instances workers | \
    perl -e '@_ = <>; shift @_; print $_[rand @_]'
)
```

After this command you are ready to use `machine` and `zone` variables, e.g.:

```
gcloud compute --project "my-project" ssh --zone "$zone" "$machine"
```

**Explanations**

The *perl* command reads all lines from the standard input into `@_` array using the diamond operator `<>`. Then [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) function removes the first item from `@_`. [`rand`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html)`@_` returns a random decimal number between zero and the number of items in `@_`. The decimal number is implicitly converted to integer in the index context. Therefore, the result of `$_[rand @_]` is a random item of `@_`, i.e. a random line from the output of the *gcloud* command.

The output of *gcloud* and *perl* commands is captured using [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) and passed to the *read* command via [here string](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html).

I have quoted *words* in the first paragraph, because the shell interprets character sequences as words depending on the [`IFS`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_03) (*Input Field Separators*) variable. So the `IFS`-separated words from the here string are assigned to `machine` (the first word), `zone` (the second word), and `unused` (the rest of the line) variables.

`-r` option disables the special meaning of backslash. In other words, *read* will not try to interpret escape sequences in the input, when this option is given.

**The Case of Big Number of Lines**

Note, the solution implies that the output of *gcloud* command is relatively small, i.e. small enough to slurp the entire file into an array. This operation is fast, but requires more memory as opposed to reading line by line using a `while <>` loop. Here is another solution for the off-chance if the output is very large, or memory is very limited:

```
read -r machine zone unused <<< $(
  gcloud compute instance-groups list-instances workers | \
    perl -e '<>; $. = 0; rand($.) < 1 && ($line = $_) while <>; print $line'
)
```

where `<>` reads the header; `$.` is the built-in variable keeping the current line number; and the rest is taken from [this cookbook](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch08_07.htm).

Comment: Nicely done, especially the memory-efficient 2nd `perl` command. While it doesn't make a difference in this case, I still suggest double-quoting the command substitution to promote good habits.

Answer (score 2):

If the input from which to extract a random line is large, and you want to avoid reading it into memory *as a whole*, as `shuf` does, consider the 2nd `perl` solution in [Ruslan Osmanov's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41793220/45375).

Otherwise, [hansaplast's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41791557/45375) uses a multi-utility approach based on `shuf` that is easy to understand, but it can be streamlined (and, as of this writing, has flaws):

```
read -r machine zone _ < \ 
  <(gcloud compute instance-groups list-instances workers | tail +2 | shuf -n 1)

gcloud compute --project "my-project" ssh --zone "$zone" "$machine"
```

- By making `read` read the output from a process substitution (`<(...)`), it is ensured that `read` is executed in the *current* shell, which means that the variables it creates are visible to the remaining commands, notably the 2nd `gcloud` call.

  - By contrast, if you use a pipeline (`gcloud ... | read ...`), `read` executes in a *subshell*, and the variables it creates won't be seen by subsequent commands.
- `tail +2` skips the first line in the input (the header row).
- `shuf -n 1` extracts 1 randomly chosen line from the input.
- Note the `_` as the name of the 3rd variable passed to `read`, which receives the (unused) *rest* of the input line after the first 2 whitespace-separated tokens have been read into `$machine` and `$zone`.

  - If we only specified `machine` and `zone`, the `$zone` would receive not just the 2nd token, but the entire rest of the input line.